# Is there any experimental evidence of CTC?

Tags: general-relativity, time, time-travel, closed-timelike-curve, interstellar-travel

One consequence of general relativity is a solution called the closed time like curve or CTC...which could allow you to view a place at an earlier point in time or possibly even travel back in time.

This sounds like pure mysticism, someone please explain how this really works. Is there any evidence of it most importantly?

If this time travel stuff is real, then what technology is necessary to build the time machine or teleported or whatever this is?

Comment: I do not need a closed timelike curve in order to view a place (for example the sun) at an earlier time (for example eight minutes ago).

Comment: Also, if you are moving along a closed timelike curve (or any other cutve) you are always, at every moment, moving **forward** in time.

Comment: I’m not referring to the semantics of the definition of time, I’m referring to the observation of events that occurred before the “time machine departure.”

Comment: "before" according to what ordering?  there is no natural way to order all of the events along a CTC.

Comment: Before according to our conventional ordering of events, aside from the CTC.

Comment: There is no such thing as "our conventional ordering of events".

Comment: *If this time travel stuff is real, then what technology is necessary to build the time machine or teleported or whatever this is?* If the chronology protection conjecture holds, then no technology can accomplish this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_protection_conjecture

Comment: Supposing you could go back in time, you wouldn't find anything, because all the rest of the universe has stayed here in the now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no experimental evidence for closed time-like curves.

Comment: Is there any experimental disproof?

Comment: No. You can’t experimentally show that they don’t exist.

Comment: @Joeseph123 you can't experimentally prove inexistence of anything — only existence.